# Method of Eigenfunction Expansion

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The solution of a PDE can be represented by a Fourier cosine series
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n(t)\cos\frac{n\pi x}L.
$$

Applying a given initial condition

$$
u(x,0)=100,
$$

lets us solve for $A_n(0)$ through the orthogonality of cosines:

$$\begin{align}
u(x,0)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n(0)\cos\frac{n\pi x}L=100\\
&\Rightarrow A_n(0)=\frac{400}L\int_0^L\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\,dx=0.
\end{align}$$

This does not seem correct, however. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the $n=0$ term in your cosine expansion.

If you choose to expand your $f(x)$ in terms of cosine, then you need to have
[$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n \cos(n \pi x/L)$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Fourier.27s_formula_for_2.CF.80-periodic_functions_using_sines_and_cosines)

Comment: But $n=1,2,\dots$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, the problem is given without an $A_0$ term. Could this be a typo?

Comment: @JosuéMolina If you choose to expand in cos then you need to have the $n=0$ term. However, if you choose to expand in $\sin$ you will not have the $n=0$ term.